# Can I connect to active directory port 636 without an SSL cert?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, ssl-certificate

So I'm looking into programatically creating users in active directory from ruby using the ruby ldap lib. But I've ran into this issue were it appears that I cannot create passwords on port 389. From googling around it seems that the only way to set a password is on port 636. But I can't seem to figure out how to connect to it (even with a self signed cert).

I've downloaded ldp.exe on my local windows server 2003 and I have no problems connecting to 389 but 636 I just end up with a `Server error: <empty>` & `Cannot open connection`.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Was the information I found regarding creating passwords on 636 correct? (can we only create passwords for users on port 636?)
2. Is it possible to connect to port 636 without any certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is nothing that will prevent you from using port 389.  It is not *recommended* though because any password information you send is unencrypted and subject to being captured by someone snooping the network.
2. Commutation on port 636 requires a proper certificate setup on your LDAP server and the client you are connecting from.